# AWS JAVA SDK get public IP of Task

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ip, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a small problem. I am starting a Task (docker container) via the JAVA SDK. This is working great.

But now I want to grab the public IP via the SDK and don't know how.

here is my existing code so far.

```
RunTaskRequest request = new RunTaskRequest()
                .withCluster("JuiceShop")
                .withTaskDefinition("startJuiceShop:1")
                .withNetworkConfiguration(networkConfiguration)
                .withLaunchType("FARGATE");
RunTaskResult response = client.runTask(request);
```

The response contains the Container but the network devices aren't attached yet. Is there a simple way to get the public IPV4?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to make multiple AWS API calls to get Public IPv4 address. Here are the steps.

1. Once you perform taskRun operation. Keep taskFullArn from Output.
2. With above taskArn and cluster name, make describeTasks operation call.
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ecs/AmazonECS.html#describeTasks-com.amazonaws.services.ecs.model.DescribeTasksRequest-.

Example -

```
AmazonECS client = AmazonECSClientBuilder.standard().build();
DescribeTasksRequest request = new DescribeTasksRequest().withTasks("c5cba4eb-5dad-405e-96db-71ef8eefe6a8");
DescribeTasksResult response = client.describeTasks(request);
```

3. Above API will give you a response with network attachment details.

> "attachments": [
>                       {
>                           "id": "xxxxx-d02c-4a9d-ae79-xxxxxxx",
>                           "type": "ElasticNetworkInterface",
>                           "status": "ATTACHED",
>                           "details": [
>                               {
>                                   "name": "subnetId",
>                                   "value": "subnet-xxxxx"
>                               },
>                               {
>                                   "name": "networkInterfaceId",
>                                   "value": "eni-e5aa89a3"
>                               },
>                               {
>                                   "name": "macAddress",
>                                   "value": "xxxxx"
>                               },
>                               {
>                                   "name": "privateIPv4Address",
>                                   "value": "172.31.94.215"
>                               }
>                           ]
>                       }
>                   ],

4. Take networkInterfaceId from above API response and make following call.
5. Call AWS EC2 describeNetworkInterfaces. 
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html#describeNetworkInterfaces-com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.DescribeNetworkInterfacesRequest-

Example -

```
AmazonEC2 client = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard().build();
DescribeNetworkInterfacesRequest request = new DescribeNetworkInterfacesRequest().withNetworkInterfaceIds("eni-e5aa89a3");
DescribeNetworkInterfacesResult response = client.describeNetworkInterfaces(request);
```

6. Above should give DescriberNetworkInterfaceResult with PublicIp of container.
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/NetworkInterfaceAssociation.html#getPublicIp--

> {
>       "NetworkInterfaces": [
>           {
>               "Association": {
>                   "IpOwnerId": "amazon",
>                   "PublicDnsName": "ec2-52-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
>                   "PublicIp": "52.xx.xx.xx"
>               }
>       ] }

7. Note - You will need to perform Step-2 untill task is up and running, otherwise you will not get desired result. So probably, sleep for couple of seconds after runTask and see if Task is up and running then perform remaining steps.

Answer (score 0):

The [task metadata endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v2.html) will let you fetch network information about your container. If you're attaching an EIP you'll have to use the IPv4 from the container to find the EIP with the SDK.

[Looks like there's a metadata service v3 now!](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v3.html)

Comment: I believe this only returns the private IP, or at least the docs only show private IPs.  

There is a [v4 metadata endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4.html) now also!

Answer (score 0):

Using AWS Java SDK version 1.12.686 (2024), you should do the following described below to get the Public IP associated to a running task:

```
private static final String AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "AK........";
private static final String AWS_SECRET_KEY = "xxxx.....";
private static final String DEFAULT_AWS_REGION = "us-east-1";

AmazonECS ecsClient = AmazonECSClientBuilder.standard()
                                                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY)))
                                                .withRegion(DEFAULT_AWS_REGION)
                                                .build();
        ListClustersResult clusters = ecsClient.listClusters();
        for (String clusterArn : clusters.getClusterArns()) {
            ListTasksRequest tasksRequest = new ListTasksRequest().withCluster(clusterArn).withServiceName("your-cluster-service-name");
            ListTasksResult tasks = ecsClient.listTasks(tasksRequest);
            DescribeTasksRequest request = new DescribeTasksRequest().withTasks(tasks.getTaskArns()).withCluster(clusterArn);
            DescribeTasksResult response = ecsClient.describeTasks(request);
            for (Task task : response.getTasks()) {

                String eniId = task.getAttachments().get(0).getDetails().stream().filter(kv -> "networkInterfaceId".equals(kv.getName())).findFirst().orElse(new KeyValuePair()).getValue();
                if (StringUtils.hasText(eniId)) {
                    DescribeNetworkInterfacesRequest describeNetworkInterfacesRequest = new DescribeNetworkInterfacesRequest()
                            .withNetworkInterfaceIds(eniId);

                    AmazonEC2 amazonEC2 = AmazonEC2Client.builder().standard()
                            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY)))
                            .withRegion(DEFAULT_AWS_REGION)
                            .build();
                    DescribeNetworkInterfacesResult networkResult = amazonEC2.describeNetworkInterfaces(describeNetworkInterfacesRequest);
                    log.info("*** Public IP: " + networkResult.getNetworkInterfaces().get(0).getAssociation().getPublicIp());
                }
            }
```