# Fetch the public IP of AWS Task in a cluster using Java AWS SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk

I have created a cluster, resource, service inside a stack using Java AWS SDK.
Now I need to fetch the Public IP of the task inside the cluster.

I have used ClientFormationCloud and am trying to fetch the IP using this client itself.

I have used the following code as of now:

```
    String awsRegion = System.getenv("AWS_DEFAULT_REGION");
    Region region = Region.of(awsRegion);
    
    CloudFormationClient cfClient = CloudFormationClient.builder().region(region)
            .credentialsProvider(EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.create()).build();

    CloudFormationWaiter waiter = cfClient.waiter();
    Collection<Capability> capabilities = new ArrayList<Capability>();
    capabilities.add(Capability.CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM);

    CreateStackRequest stackRequest = CreateStackRequest.builder().stackName(stackName).templateURL(location).capabilities(capabilities).roleARN(roleARN).onFailure(OnFailure.ROLLBACK).build();

    CreateStackResponse cfResponse = cfClient.createStack(stackRequest);

    DescribeStacksRequest stacksRequest = DescribeStacksRequest.builder().stackName(stackName).build();
    DescribeStacksResponse response = cfClient.describeStacks();
    WaiterResponse<DescribeStacksResponse> waiterResponse = waiter.waitUntilStackCreateComplete(stacksRequest);
    waiterResponse.matched().response().ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

'''

EDITED

Tried the following for ECS according to the first comment

'''

```
AmazonECS ecsClient = AmazonECSClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(System.getenv("AWS_DEFAULT_REGION")).withCredentials(new com.amazonaws.auth.EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider()).build();
ListTasksRequest request = new ListTasksRequest().withCluster("ClusterName");
ListTasksResult tasks = ecsClient.listTasks(request);
List<String> taskArns = tasks.getTaskArns();
        for (String taskArn : taskArns) {
            System.out.println(taskArn);
            DescribeTasksRequest dtr = new DescribeTasksRequest().withTasks(taskArn);
            DescribeTasksResult response = ecsClient.describeTasks(dtr);
        }
```

'''

The taskArn is getting printed: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:892372858130:task/ClusterName/2c72e43671ef4cc09f7816469696ee3e

But the last line of the code is giving the following error:

com.amazonaws.services.ecs.model.InvalidParameterException: Invalid identifier: Identifier is for cluster NaraCluster. Your cluster is default (Service: AmazonECS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: 45f8abfc-66d4-4808-8810-b6e314bb1b15; Proxy: null)

Comment: You need to describe the ECS service to get a list of tasks, then you need to describe the task to get the ENI, then you need to describe the ENI to get the IP. It is a long winded process. The last 2/3 are covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946160/aws-java-sdk-get-public-ip-of-task

Comment: Edited the question, pls check @luk2302

Answer (score 0):

As far as the error `Invalid identifier: Identifier is for cluster NaraCluster. Your cluster is default`

Turns out the solution was stupid obvious, right in the error message. I needed to add `withCluster` to my call.

```
final UpdateServiceRequest request = new UpdateServiceRequest()
                .withCluster(clusterId)
                .withService(serviceArn)
                .withDesiredCount(desiredCount);
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ecs/model/UpdateServiceRequest.html#withCluster-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0):

Using AWS Java SDK version 1.12.686 (2024), you should do the following described below to get the Public IP associated with a running task:

```
private static final String AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "AK........";
private static final String AWS_SECRET_KEY = "xxxx.....";
private static final String DEFAULT_AWS_REGION = "us-east-1";

AmazonECS ecsClient = AmazonECSClientBuilder.standard()
                                                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY)))
                                                .withRegion(DEFAULT_AWS_REGION)
                                                .build();
        ListClustersResult clusters = ecsClient.listClusters();
        for (String clusterArn : clusters.getClusterArns()) {
            ListTasksRequest tasksRequest = new ListTasksRequest().withCluster(clusterArn).withServiceName("your-cluster-service-name");
            ListTasksResult tasks = ecsClient.listTasks(tasksRequest);
            DescribeTasksRequest request = new DescribeTasksRequest().withTasks(tasks.getTaskArns()).withCluster(clusterArn);
            DescribeTasksResult response = ecsClient.describeTasks(request);
            for (Task task : response.getTasks()) {

                String eniId = task.getAttachments().get(0).getDetails().stream().filter(kv -> "networkInterfaceId".equals(kv.getName())).findFirst().orElse(new KeyValuePair()).getValue();
                if (StringUtils.hasText(eniId)) {
                    DescribeNetworkInterfacesRequest describeNetworkInterfacesRequest = new DescribeNetworkInterfacesRequest()
                            .withNetworkInterfaceIds(eniId);

                    AmazonEC2 amazonEC2 = AmazonEC2Client.builder().standard()
                            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY)))
                            .withRegion(DEFAULT_AWS_REGION)
                            .build();
                    DescribeNetworkInterfacesResult networkResult = amazonEC2.describeNetworkInterfaces(describeNetworkInterfacesRequest);
                    log.info("*** Public IP: " + networkResult.getNetworkInterfaces().get(0).getAssociation().getPublicIp());
                }
            }
```